# Create SPListItem from SPItemEventDataCollection in ItemUpdating event

Tags: sharepoint, properties, updating, splistitem

In SharePoint 2010 I want to execute some code when a list item is updating - when the ItemUpdating event is fired.

What I need is a SPListItem containing the old values (before updating) and another SPListItem containing the new values.

I can easily get the SPListItem with the old values by:

```
SPItemEventProperties properties;
properties.ListItem;
```

but I can't get the SPListItem with the new values. The only thing I can get is from

```
SPItemEventProperties properties
properties.AfterProperties
```

but that gives me a SPListEventDataCollection. I would like to convert this SPListEventDataCollection into a SPListItem - is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The updated SPListItem does not yet exist within the ItemUpdating event.

Check [this page](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122).

You want to listen in to the ItemUpdat**ed** event and you can get the new ListItem there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...

```
if (properties.ListItem["title"] != properties.AfterProperties["title"])
{
    //do something because the title has changed
}
```